# How to use JS file in laravel Blade Template?

Tags: javascript, laravel

i need a math calculation in laravel blade template.

Html :

```
<div class="col-md-1">
                <label for=" ">Qunatity</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="total_Qut" id="t1" onkeyup="val()" placeholder="Qunatity" >
                <div class="invalid-feedback">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <label for="validationCustom05">Rate/Unit</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="rate" id="t2" onkeyup="val()" placeholder="Price Per Unit" required>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">

                </div>
```

i call JS :

```
function id(id){return document.getElementById(id);}
         var val1 = 0;
         var val2 = 0;
        function val()
        {
        val1 = parseInt(id("t1").value);
        val2 = parseInt(id("t2").value);
        id("tot").innerHTML = ((val1 > 0 && val2 > 0))? val1 * val2 : 0;
        };
```

> I tried 3 Ways : 
>   1. add in the below of section.
>
> 2. Added to header.
> 3. @stack - i dont know, How to use this.
>
> Whats is the best practice to add the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer the 3rd way, as it's only going to load it on the page not other pages.
To do the third option, you could edit your master blade page which normally is `layouts/app.blade.php` and add a `@stack('js')` where you want your javascript to be. (at the end of `<body>`)

then in any blade file that has `@extends('layouts.app')` you can then use

```html
@push('js')
<script src="{{ asset('js/myjavascript.js')}}"></script>
@endpush
```

Comment: No. I tried. There have any errors in my code ?,  But its not working..

Comment: Now its working. i update @stact missing.. Thanks bro. Lot